# Passing id of html image to javascript on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to pass the id/name of an html image when you click on it? It seems the onclick function is defunct now, and I can't seem to find anything with a similar functionality.

Each image has a unique id, which is set at creation, by the name variable. This is how I am creating the clickable images

```
function addbutton(position, name) {
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    var imgURL = chrome.extension.getURL("icons/donate.png");
    element.setAttribute("type", "image");
    element.setAttribute("src", imgURL);
    element.setAttribute("class", "addressbuttons");
    element.setAttribute("id", name); //the name variable is set to a specific text
    element.setAttribute("onclick", "SubmissionInfo()"); //what can I replace onclick with?
    position.parentNode.insertBefore(element, position.nextSibling);
}
```

I want this function to run with the context of which image was clicked by using the contents of the name variable, as well as the x,y coords of the images

```
function SubmissionInfo() {
 ...
}
```

I know `SubmissionInfo()` should be globally accessible in its own .js file, but I don't know how to get it to detect the image being clicked and how to get the id of the image.

Also, I've only been working with both html and javascript for a few hours now, so I apologize for any major mistakes I might have made.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the id of the element that triggers the onclick using `this.id`

```
element.setAttribute("onclick", "SubmissionInfo(this.id)");
```

Change the SubmissionInfo() function accordingly

```
function SubmissionInfo(id) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: is this possible in a chrome extension? Because that is what I am using this for, and I think I read somewhere that onclick is no longer allowed. Apologies, probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: `onclick` works on all browsers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526478/javascript-onclick-cross-browser-friendly

Answer (score 0):

Inside the below function you can get id of clicked image by

```
function SubmissionInfo(){
    alert(this.id);  //this would refered the current clicked image.

},
```

And for your comment,
You can use the `element.addEventListener('click', SubmissionInfo)` instead of `element.setAttribute("onclick", "SubmissionInfo()");`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this -

```
element.addEventListener('click', 'SubmissionInfo(event)');

function SubmissionInfo(event){
    do_my_stuff_with_id(event.currentTarget.id);
}
```

And you are right onclick does not work on chrome ext.

Comment: I tried this, but it seems the 'SubmissionInfo(event)' is not working. it only does anything when the two '' are removed. However, when they are, chrome keeps complaining about SubmissionInfo not being defined.